# Getting *** Could not read served logs: Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol while accessing DAG task logs in aks hosted airflow

Tags: postgresql, azure, airflow

After running DAG in airflow hosted in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS), opening task log shows message "*** Could not read served logs: Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol".
Airflow setup: Setup done using helm chart and have set azure postgres db as metadata database for airflow using custom configs in override-values.yaml.

Command used for setting up airflow helm:

```
# Add helm repo for airflow
helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org
# Install airflow helm chart version 1.11.0 with custom configurations 
helm upgrade airflow apache-airflow/airflow --version 1.11.0 --install --namespace <namespace> --create-namespace -f override-values.yaml
```

Here is my override-values.yaml

```
webserverSecretKey: "<webserver secret key created using official helm production guide>"
scheduler:
  waitForMigrations:
    enabled: false
initDb:
  enabled: true
# Disable postgre instance to be created
postgresql:
  enabled: false
# Update storage class name for logs pvc to be managed-premium
logs:
  persistence:
    storageClassName: managed-premium
# Update storage class name for dags pvc to be managed-premium
dags:
  persistence:
    storageClassName: managed-premium
# Update storage class name for triggerer pvc to be managed-premium
triggerer:
  persistence:
    storageClassName: managed-premium
# Update storage class name for workers pvc to be managed-premium
workers:
  persistence:
    storageClassName: managed-premium
# For Postgres azure connection
pgbouncer:
 enabled: true
pgbouncer:
  # The maximum number of connections to PgBouncer
  maxClientConn: 100
  # The maximum number of server connections to the metadata database from PgBouncer
  metadataPoolSize: 10
  # The maximum number of server connections to the result backend database from PgBouncer
  resultBackendPoolSize: 5
env:
  - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__TEST_CONNECTION
    value: Enabled
  - name: AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__EXPOSE_CONFIG
    value: 'true'
  - name: AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS
    value: "airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth"
# For Postgres azure connection
data:
  metadataSecretName: <secret having azure postgres database connection string>
# For DAGs git sync
dags:
  gitSync:
    enabled: true
    repo: <repo url>
    branch: "<branch name in repo>"
    subPath: ""
    sshKeySecret: <secret holding ssh key for repo>
```

'managed-premium' is custom storage class available in aks

Please help if anyone faced similar issue or know how to solve this. Thanks in advance

P.S. : I am new to airflow but able to setup airflow in aks cluster using helm chart. It looks like I am missing a config here but not sure how to fix